# Pass the element itself as an onClick parameter instead of an instance of a class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to change the inner text of a button that is rendered by a class. Because of that, when I use the `this` keyword, React imagine that I want to pass the object of that class instead of the element itself.

Here I have my sample React code that doesn't work:

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
    
    helloWorld(element) {
        element.innerText = 'Hello Wolrd!';
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.helloWorld(this)}>Change it!</button> 
        )
    }
}
```

And here I have a vanila JavaScript code that gets the expected result

```html
<button onclick=helloWorld(this)>Change it!</button> 
<script>
  function helloWorld(element) {
    element.innerText='Hello World!';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword *this* in a React component refers to the component itself as you guessed.
You need to add a parameter event to the onClick method :

```html
<button onClick={(e) => this.helloWorld(e.target)}>Change it!</button>
```